# How to cancel previous actions in java spring mvc application

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am developing a spring MVC application. I ran into some interesting case.

To make it easier to explain i am taking the stackover flow buttons on the top as example( i mean those questions, tags, users, badges, unanswered buttons).

Now in my app i have similar buttons. when user clicks on any button it makes ajax call by passing proper arguments. Server makes sql queries and returns the results back.

Now assume that there is a crazy user like me who keeps on clicking those buttons without break. So each click is making a ajax call. And which ever completes its operation is showing up on front end. So even if the user clicks Tags button in the last it may show up and again the previous click on questions which took long time to return to front end can overwrite the page. How can i fix that? ( i want the tags data to be shown as it is the users last click)

In the first place i know that when user first clicks on question and then on tag i no longer need to query sql for questions button. Is there some way for me to stop processing the sql query for questions button.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle this is through the user interface - if the user takes some action (clicking an image) that will require significant processing on the backend, your UI should prevent other actions on the page from sending further messages to the backend until the original request is complete.

Ways to tackle this visually would be to disable/gray out other elements, make it obvious that some work is going on (with spinners, progress bars), etc.

On the server side, since each HTTP request is independent it would be cumbersome and difficult to add logic on the server to be able to detect if the user making this current request has another ongoing request currently being processed.

Comment: I have so many places in my page which can make ajax call. Is there some simple way to disable everything else until ajax call finishes.

Comment: @JavaMan You can look into a modal dialog showing work is processing. That way everything will be disabled until the call returns. [Example](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to take help of cookies. When the first time the action is done, write some cookie. Every time, check that cookie before you process.

You cannot simply disable a link or button from the UI and hope the user cannot do it. It can always be done in multiple ways. Additional checking is must.

(I haven't read your post completely. But from what I understand from the 1st answer...)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and I tackled it this way.

I did hand-coded ajax calls (as opposed to jQuery etc.)

I had a single global XMLHTTPRequest.

```
var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
```

When the user clicked something, which needed an ajax call, I aborted the previous call, if already running.

```
if( xhr.readystate !=0 || xhr.readystate !=4 )
   xhr.abort();
```

Then create a new instance of XHR, and do your business.

```
xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
xhr.open("GET", myUrl, true);
//attach callback function etc and do the send
```

Comment: With this approach still server is processing the unnecessary requests. Did you get a solution for it?

Comment: If you see, my code used `GET`, and my impl on server was idempotent, so I never bothered about the server processing the calls. And I believed you had the same scenario because you gave example of the buttons, which are plain `GET`. If your ajax call is not idempotent, thats a different ballgame altogether. But more details can certainly help determine what to do.